Does Apache Ignite's Colocation feature apply to the Spark Dataframe extension?
When using the Ignite Spark dataframe extension, like
val result = df.groupBy("field").count
will the Spark dataframe extension only processes the group by on Ignite nodes that the data resides on?
The documenation here: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/collocated-computations says

Colocated computation is type of distributed data processing wherein the computational task you want to perform over a specific data set is sent to the nodes where the required data is located and only the results of the computations are sent back.

but the Ignite spark documentation here: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/ignite-dataframe makes no mention of co-location.
